# Variable set to false

Tags: php

I wrote this REALLY simple code:

```
$foo=false;
echo $foo;//It outputs nothing
```

Why? Shouldn't it output `false`? What can I do to make that work?

Comment: Prefer `var_dump` for debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`false` evaluates to an empty string when printing to the page.

Use

```
echo $foo ? "true" : "false";
```

Comment: To add, you can also var_dump($foo) to get something like "Boolean: (False)" printed

Answer (score 3):

The string "false" is not equal to `false`.  When you convert `false` to a string, you get an empty string.

What you have is implicitly doing this:  `echo (string) $foo;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see a "true" or "false" string when you echo for tests etc you could always use a simple function like this:

```
// Boolean to string function
function booleanToString($bool){
    if (is_bool($bool) === true) {
        if($bool == true){ 
            return "true";  
        } else { 
            return "false";
        } 
    } else { 
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
// Setup some boolean variables 
$Var_Bool_01 = true;
$Var_Bool_02 = false;

// Echo the results using the function
echo "Boolean 01 = " . booleanToString($Var_Bool_01) . "<br />"; // true
echo "Boolean 02 = " . booleanToString($Var_Bool_02) . "<br />"; // false
```